# is there a callback method that tells when a UITableViewController has finished creating the cells of a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, loading

Is there an iOS / Swift 3.0 callback method that tells  when a **UITableViewController** has finished loading (creating the cells of) a **UITableView** (after calling the .reloadData on the table view (in Swift)?

(or alternative method)

Comment: what would you want to do inside this method ? Maybe knowing this can lead to me (or someone) suggesting something.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I would like to get the list of visible cells and then perform an API call to pre-load only the data relative to those (e.g. master / detail view scenario, where the master shows a table with a list of available data from a first API call and the detailed view shows the data that is fetched from a second API call.

Comment: What do you mean by "finishes loading"?

Comment: Why not load the data *before* the table is done "creating the cells"? You have data in your data source presumably by then, so why not load it as soon as you're ready?

Comment: there is a visibleCells property that tells you all the cells currently in view. But I think the function you want is tableView(_:didEndDisplaying:forRowAt:)

Comment: @ShawnFrank that method is called when a row is scrolled _off screen_

Comment: Have you looked at `UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching` protocol?

Comment: @AshleyMills - yes you are right, perhaps this will be of more use: tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 1):

The func you're looking for doesn't exist, but per your comment above, would it be possible to get each cell (or some model object it takes as a property) to make the API pre-load call? In this way, data will only be pre-loaded for visible cells. When new cells are scrolled into view, their data will be loaded in turn.

For example, in your cell:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    var someObject: MyObject {
        didSet {
            someObject?.loadData()
        }
    }
}
```

and in your view controller:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! "MyCell"
    cell.someObject = myObjects[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

This way you're only loading data for cells in view. If you were to add:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.someObject.cancelLoading()
}
```

You can ensure that objects in cells no longer view aren't loaded if not required.

Comment: I think he means you use cellForRowAtIndexPath for example, so when you create a cell you also fetch the info. But I strongly suggest to not do this as it sounds like you are not doing it the right way.

Comment: @Simon which way would you recommend? I have just drafted a method that fetches only the visible cells that have not been fetched every time a user interaction has ended based on the visible indexes. Does this sound sensible to you?

Comment: @mm24 There is a method that is called when a cell is about to be displayed (that is, when the user scrolls to that cell and the cell was not visible before).

Comment: @mm24 If I scroll through your list of things, do you really want to prefetch all the 129 items which I passed while scrolling? What kind of calls do you need to fetch the data for the cell. Have you tried if it is fast enough without prefetching?